# gmailsender not working when using proguard

Tags: android

I am using the gmailsender to send email in my app. I followed the link below [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

I have however noticed that whenever I use proguard to build my APK, then the gmail sender does not work(when I install that APK). There is no error thrown, but emails are not sent. If I disable proguard and then generate the APK, then it works fine using that APK.

Can anyone please suggest what might be wrong here.

:::EDIT:::-ADDED FEW ERROR MESAGE(abridged) LINES FROM CONSOLE WHILE GENERATING APK. I COULD GET RID OF THOSE WARNING HOWEVER BY IGNORING THEM IN PROGUARD CONFIG FILE

```
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find 
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] Warning: there were 247 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-07-09 10:00:38 - ]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:49
```

Comment: are u check all jar files import and export on your project properties?

Comment: yes, they are all there. Or else I will receive runtime error anyway which I am not.

Comment: can you tell me runtime error logcat messsage?

Comment: updated my question to add console warning message I had received while exporting my project as APK. There was no logcat error messages. These console warning messages were however got rid of when I added -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.*
-ignorewarnings in proguard config file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally solved the problem by updating to latest version of proguard from 4.7 to 4.9.

also added the following to the proguard config file

```
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn java.beans.Beans
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-keep class javamail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.mail.** {*;}
-keep class javax.activation.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.dsn.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.handlers.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
-keep class com.sun.mail.util.** {*;}
-keep class mailcap.** {*;}
-keep class mimetypes.** {*;}
-keep class myjava.awt.datatransfer.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.awt.** {*;}
-keep class org.apache.harmony.misc.** {*;}
```

Comment: PS: in the file : proguard.cfg
 Thank you so match for your answer !! you really helped me !!!